# Regex_match for validationg string from selectbox in codeigniter

Tags: php, regex, codeigniter

I have this code in my view:

```
echo form_label('State', 'state');
$options = array(   
      'No state' => '- Select state -',
      'Alabama' => 'Alabama',
      'Florida' => 'Florida',
      'California' => 'California',

);
echo form_dropdown('state', $options);
echo form_error('state', '<div class="error">', '</div>');
```

And in my controller this:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('state', 'State', 'required|regex_match[??????]');
if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
   {
   // VALIDATION ERROR
   $this->load->view('page_registration');
   }
   else
   {
   // VALIDATION SUCCESS
   ....
   ....
   ....
```

My question is what to type inside regex_match instead of the question marks, so when everythng else instead of No state is selected it  will succed. If you select No state, then the registration page reload and shows the error.

I need the regular expression code between the square brackets for regex_match.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why dont you put a Zero in the array

```
$options = array(   
      '0' => '- Select state -',
      'Alabama' => 'Alabama',
      'Florida' => 'Florida',
      'California' => 'California',

);
```

And then in your controller you might use

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('state', 'State', 'required|alpha');
```

EDIT:

If you want to stick with regex and validate NOT ALPHA you can use something like this

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('state', 'state', 'trim|required|regex_match[/^[a-zA-Z]$/]');
```

Hope it helps

Comment: yes, but I want exactly the opposite. I want NOT ALPHA and this is not in form validation library so I have to use ragex_match, but it is not working and throwing an error Message: preg_match() [function.preg-match]: No ending delimiter '^' found

Answer (score 2):

Try: `/^(?!(No state)).*$/` (I wrapped the regexp for pregmatch, sorry that i forgot earlier)

Translated : The string should not begin with 'No state'. ( so 'No state my friend' would failed)

Result:

```
preg_match('/^(?!(No state)).*$/', 'No state', $matches);
array()

preg_match('/^(?!(No state)).*$/', 'Alabama', $matches);
array ( 0 => 'Alabama' )
```

Regex are usefull so try to learn the syntax (google for a tutorial, there is plenty availables)

Comment: it gives me this error: Message: preg_match() [function.preg-match]: No ending delimiter '^' found